# How to give page link to View Cart & Checkout on Mini Cart Icon

Tags: magento2

How to give page link to View Cart & Checkout on Mini Cart Icon ? using Magento ver. 2.2.6

[MiniCart Magento ver. 2.2.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96XSY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento2 already has this feature. You can config this by go to Stores/Configuration, click on tab Sales, then Checkout, you can see which you want:
[image]